# py file call successful but no output

Tags: php, python, batch-file, cmd, exec

im trying to execute an py file from php,  using bat file .
the whole code works fine and im trying to execute an file name dbConn.py
the file executes when seperatly double clicked i.e executed and output is reflected
the code from php is this:

```
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

      mysqli_close($conn);
      $cmd = "run_dbConn.bat" ;
      execInBackground($cmd);
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
```

This is code for runcmd.php

```
  <?php
    function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
    pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
     else { 
     exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
   }
   ?>
```

and code for run_dbConn.bat

```
  cd C:\xampp\htdocs\eclipse_workspace\Project
  python dbConn.py
  ECHO %1 
  echo
```

even the above code make the file to run , which i have checked from task bar. but the output is not generated or reflected. the dbConn.py does not have something related to code and can be executed separately....
plzz help me out even a suggestion will be well.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

This line will run the command and redirect the output to a null device, aka hides the output.

Try removing 
`> /dev/null`

Comment: no.. it does not help. actually the file makes some entry in database when executed... any other help plzz

Comment: Are you on windows or linux?